# linking to a google cloud bucket file in a terminal command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm trying to find my way with Google Cloud.

I have a Debian VM Instance that I am running a server on. It is installed and working via SSH Connection in a browser window. The command to start the server is "./ninjamsrv config-file-path.cfg"

I have the config file in my default google firebase storage bucket as I will need to update it regularly.

I want to start the server referencing the cfg file in the bucket, e.g:
"./ninjamsrv gs://my-bucket/ninjam-config.cfg"

But the file is not found:
error opening configfile 'gs://my-bucket/ninjam-config.cfg'
Error loading config file!

However if I run:
"gsutil acl get gs://my-bucket/"

I see:

```
[
  {
    "entity": "project-editors-XXXXX",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "XXXXX",
      "team": "editors"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-owners-XXXXX",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "XXXXX",
      "team": "owners"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-viewers-XXXXX",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "XXXXX",
      "team": "viewers"
    },
    "role": "READER"
  }
]
```

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to verify is if indeed the error thrown is a permission one. Checking the logs related to the VM’s operations will certainly provide more details in that aspect, and a 403 error code would confirm if this is a permission issue. If the VM is a Compute Engine one, you can refer to [this documentation about logging.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/audit-logging)
If the error is indeed a permission one, then you should verify if the permissions for this object are set as “fine-grained” access. This would mean that each object would have its own set of permissions, regardless of the bucket-level access set. You can [read more about this here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control). You could either change the level of access to “uniform” which would grant access to all objects in the relevant bucket, or make the appropriate permissions change for this particular object.

If the issue is not a permission one, then I would recommend trying to start the server from the same .cfg file hosted on the local directory of the VM. This might point the error at the file itself, and not its hosting on Cloud Storage. In case the server starts successfully from there, you may want to re-upload the file to GCS in case the file got corrupted during the initial upload.

Comment: hi there @PYB, thanks a lot for your explanation. I checked the logs for the bucket in Google Cloud Platform > Logs Viewer, and there are no errors relating to permissions.

You were right, the VM is indeed a compute engine one.

When I save the file to a temp folder using:
gsutil acl get gs://my-bucket/my-config.cfg > ./tmp/my-config.cfg

Then open it using:
sudo nano ./tmp/my-config.cfg

It is not my config file at all, but it contains the JSON at the top of my OP. Does this indicate a permissions error? I am a bit lost with this ;(

Thanks

Comment: 1- Have you tried to start the server from the file being in your VM’s local directory?
2- What is your role assigned project-wise? See roles here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_role_definitions
3- If you have the owner role for the project, you should be able to change the permissions for the bucket or the object following https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions
4- Have you checked if the object has “uniform” or “fine-grained” access?
5- Use the cloud console instead of gcloud commands if you are unsure of the above